# OBS-Studio Error

Tags: software-installation, obs-studio

I'm trying to install OBS-Studio on Ubuntu but I keep getting an error in the terminal. I followed the instructions on the OBS Github. This is what I'm getting in the terminal:

```
user@user-desktop:~$ sudo apt-get install obs-studio
[sudo] password for user: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libobs0 obs-plugins
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  obs-studio
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/2,910 kB of archives.
After this operation, 10.4 MB of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 171904 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../obs-studio_21.1.0-0obsproject1~bionic_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking obs-studio (21.1.0-0obsproject1~bionic) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/obs-studio_21.1.0-0obsproject1~bionic_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/obs/libobs/bicubic_scale.effect', which is also in package libobs0:amd64 21.0.2+dfsg1-1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/obs-studio_21.1.0-0obsproject1~bionic_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
user@user-desktop:~$
```

Comment: Is your 18.04 installation and upgrade from a previous OS version or was it a clean install?

Answer (score 2):

Uninstall the conflicting library

```
sudo apt-get remove libobs0
```

Attempt OBS install

```
sudo get install obs-studio
```

Comment: I also had to run `sudo apt-get autoremove` after I ran remove.

Comment: I had to `sudo apt purge libobs0`. Ironically, a standard remove of libobs0 also caused a broken pipe :rolling_eyes: reinstalled OBS after, and it seems to be fine for now.